# changing gridview 's cell value as soon as cursor goes into it

Tags: c#

I have a grid view. I want to when user edit specific cell, it's content will be changed.
For example if content is "A92-5", it changes to "A92".
now it works but after **leaving** the cell.
 I want to it occur when cursor goes into cell.

```
private void _dvg_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (_dvg.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        temp = _dvg.Rows[_dvg.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[_dvg.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        words = temp.Split('-');

        _dvg.Rows[_dvg.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[_dvg.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value = words[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `CellEnter` instead

```
private void _dvg_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (_dvg.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        temp = _dvg.Rows[_dvg.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[_dvg.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        words = temp.Split('-');

        _dvg.Rows[_dvg.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[_dvg.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Value = words[0];
    }
}
```

This will change the value when the cells gets focus (can either be by mouse click or the arrow keys)